# Google Maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

When I access the Places API, Google sends back an object with, among other things, these two properties:

```javascript
location.geometry.G
location.geometry.K
```

These represent the latitude and longitudes. I never read about these anywhere. Besides, all my codebase recently became unstable, because it recently changed for the letters H & L.

This is weird, isn't it? What did I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are undocumented properties of the API (the latitude and longitude of that particular *google.maps.LatLng* object).

Access them reliably by using the documented methods (`.lat()` and `.lng()`).