# Generic way to get latlng value when marker dragged event (Google Map)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I was using this technique to getting value of latlng when marker dragged event fired.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {

                mouseLocation = event.latLng;

                alert("Longitude = " + mouseLocation.K + " Latitude = " + mouseLocation.G)

});
```

But now mouseLocation.K and mouseLocation.G is shown undefined. This is converted to mouseLocation.H and mouseLocation.L. Is there any generic way to get both these value so i dn't need to change my code in future.

Comment: related question: [Google maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614504/google-maps-weird-geometry-location-attributes-g-k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use undocumented properties of Google Maps' objects. Just do `mouseLocation.lat()` and `mouseLocation.lng()`

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Answer (score 1):

Try  with   `event.latLng.lat() and   event.latLng.lng()`

for you : this

```
mouseLocation = event.latLng;
alert("Longitude = " + mouseLocation.lng()+ " Latitude = " + mouseLocation.lat());
```