# undefined Lat and Long google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like the lat and long coordinates. instead of the coordinateds i get this

location:
Waalre, Nederland
Address: Waalre, Nederland
Latitude: undefined
Longitude: undefined

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
    function intilize() {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtautocomplete"));

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var location = "Address: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
        location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.A + "<br/>";
        location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.F;
        document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location
        });

    };

    </script>

    <span>location:</span><input type="text" id="txtautocomplete" style="width:200px" placeholder="enter the adress"/>
    <label id="lblresult"></label>
</body>
```

Comment: duplicate of [Google maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614504/google-maps-weird-geometry-location-attributes-g-k/)

Comment: duplicate of [item.geometry.location.kb & item.geometry.location.jb returning undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mate,

.geometry.location.A/.geometry.location.F are not accessible , use lat() and lng()

change to this :

```
    location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
    location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed.

instead of "place.geometry.location.A" it must be "place.geometry.location.lat()"
and
"place.geometry.location.F" it must be "place.geometry.location.lng()"